# Create .VHD from Cloned instance of XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtual-machine

I have some old XP machines running legacy software, which I would like to port over to a windows 7 machine.

I have been toying around getting the legacy software to run in Windows Virtual PC in XP mode, and natively on windows 7, but haven't been having much luck.

What I thought was, if i could take the CURRENT XP machine, and create a .VHD file from it, I could boot into it using Windows Virtual PC.

Is it possible to take say, a clone of a system, and make it into a .VHD to boot from a virtual PC utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool exactly for this job called Disk2VHD - available from here

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd

You can then mount the .VHD using a tool such as Oracle VirtualBox

Comment: Couldn't have imagined an easier solution! Thank you.

Comment: @ThomG - Seconded, I've used this on a few older machines for archiving them prior to reinstalling, and it's worked incredibly well. Damn fine little utility.

Comment: @spikey_richie I have created .VHDK file using disk2vhd utility. But it is not supported in Virtual Box ?